# Issue with locales on custom error controller in Symfony

Tags: symfony, error-handling, localization

I overided the default ErrorController by following this guide:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller

Everything works fine, but the error page isn't translated on changing languages (/en, /de).

The locale is always set to default.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my error controller (very simplified):

```
class ErrorController extends AbstractController
{
    public function error(FlattenException $exception, Request $request){
        $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
        return $this->render("error/error{$statusCode}.html.twig", [

        ]);
    }

}
```